# Google api client for python log level and debuglevel not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine, debugging, google-api, pycharm

While building a basic python app on AppEngine I found this page:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/logging

Which states you can do the following to set the log level:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

However it doesn't seem to have any impact on the output which is always INFO for me.  I set to logging.DEBUG and don't see any debug entries.  I set to logging.WARNING and still see info entries.  Never seems to change.

I also tried setting httplib2 to debuglevel 4:

```
import httplib2
httplib2.debuglevel = 4
```

Yet I don't see any HTTP headers in the log :/

Running python 2.7.10 in PyCharm.

Has anyone got these settings to work?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced a similar issue in **python 3**, fixed it by configuring a handler for the python logger:

```py
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
```

I found this solution by wondering what handlers were initially present, and finding there were none:

```py
print(logger.handlers)  # []
```

Answer (score 1):

In PyCharm edit your project's Run configuration (`Run` -> `Edit Configurations` then select your project) and in the `Additional options` field add `--log_level=debug`.

BTW - you don't need to set the `logger` options, the above should suffice.

Comment: Thanks - this does cause one debug entry to show from crypt.py when it gets an access_token, but for the following call to the directory API I still don't see any http headers.

Comment: Unsure about logging from `httplib2` itself, I'm not using it. It *might* have something to do with GAE using its customized `urlfetch` lib under the hood to make external requests - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/issue-requests